# Azure DevOps yaml configuration with Bitbucket always return 'Forbidden'

Tags: azure-devops

I'm having issue with Az DevOps with Bitbucket connection using yaml configuration.
It always returns: "Unable to configure a service on the selected Bitbucket repository. Bitbucket returned the error 'Forbidden'."

Don't know what permissions are actually required. I can't use the owner account, we will need to config an account with just sufficient permissions to perform actions.

Typical MS error message...

Anyone has a solution for it?

Comment: Go Bitbucket repos which you will link into VSTS, ensure you can see the **Setting** tab: https://imgur.com/a/IxuFVUV . If you could not see that, that means you don't have enough permission. Contact its admin or owner, change your repos permission as Admin is better.